# unhandled exception android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Googling yields little results with regards to what I need to solve, the exception points towards some special effects controller which I am not using. Any help is welcomed

```
    [MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
    [MonoDroid] Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
    [MonoDroid]   --- End of managed Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException stack trace ---
    [MonoDroid] android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffff
    [MonoDroid]     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceTypeName(ResourcesImpl.java:310)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName(Resources.java:2334)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentAnim.loadAnimation(FragmentAnim.java:79)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController$AnimationInfo.getAnimation(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:774)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.startAnimations(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:144)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.DefaultSpecialEffectsController.executeOperations(DefaultSpecialEffectsController.java:120)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.SpecialEffectsController.executePendingOperations(SpecialEffectsController.java:294)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2190)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2088)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1990)
    [MonoDroid]     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    [MonoDroid]     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
    [MonoDroid]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    [MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    [MonoDroid]     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

**What I have tried:**
change shell presentation mode from ModalAnimated to Not Animated.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Shell.PresentationMode="NotAnimated"
             Title="New Item"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Spacing="3" Padding="15">
            <Label Text="Text" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Label Text="Description" FontSize="Medium" />
            <Editor Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoSize="TextChanges" FontSize="Medium" Margin="0" />
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
                <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Personally, I would comment out different lines, until I find out which one causes the exception. Then try to change that line until exception stops happening.

Comment: It's hard to find problems just based on above code.  If it is convinient for you , could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?